# Dropzone - Uncaught Error: No URL provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dropzone.js

I can't figure out how to get JSONresponse after uploading a file using Dropzonejs.

I have just this:

```
<script src="{% static "dropzone/dropzone.js" %}"></script>

<form id="id_dropzone" class="dropzone" action="/ajax_file_upload_handler/"
              enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"></form>
```

I think it is not possible without manually initializing dropzone so I changed it to:

```
$("#id_dropzone").dropzone({
                maxFiles: 2000,
                url: "/ajax_file_upload_handler/",
                success: function (file, response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });


<form id="id_dropzone" class="" action=""
              enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"></form>
```

Which return `Uncaught Error: No URL provided.`

How can I initialize dropzone so I can add an options like maxFiles, maxSize and get **JSON** response?

Comment: What kind of option you like to add? its not clear what you asking for. An option could be everything.

Comment: Options like maxFiles etc. But  the main problem is to catch a response.

Comment: You catching the response right now near `console.log(response);` So what is the problem with it?

Comment: Nothing is being logged except errors so there is some problem which I can't find.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

No URL provided happens when a Dropzone gets attached to an object without either:

- an action attribute on a form that tells dropzone where to post
- a configuration for specific dropzone

My bet is, that you have a race condition, where Dropzone attaches itself to an element before you configured it. Make sure that your configuration is either directly after the JS import, or that you set `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;` and instantiate the Dropzone explicitly.

Take a look over [here](https://www.questionary.wiki/en/questions/programming/dropzone-uncaught-error-no-url-provided) for more information.

```
<script src="{% static "dropzone/dropzone.js" %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

   Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#id_dropzone").dropzone({
            maxFiles: 2000,
            url: "/ajax_file_upload_handler/",
            success: function (file, response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
   })
   
</script>

<form id="id_dropzone" 
      class="dropzone" 
      action="/ajax_file_upload_handler/"
      enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      method="post">
</form>
```

Comment: But when you submit the files are empty

Answer (score -2):

The way i solved out this issue was writting a script at the end of the code and specified defer in the script to be last thing load
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltmIR.jpg)

Here is a image from my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZEm2.png)
I figure out everybody has similar code, so i hope you test and reply if you find out the solution

Comment: Please post your code directly to the post, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.