# Using Dropzone with Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

I would like to implement Dropzone in my long form. All tutorials focus on image upload ONLY, there are no tutorials if you have other stuff in your form. I am stuck in displaying dropzone. I have linked `css` and `js` files in my layout file but I still get an unstylized box for image upload and error in console:  `No URL provided.`

This is a part of my form that should display Dropzone:

```
<form action="/ads/new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="input" type="text" name="name">
<input name="file" type="file" class="dropzone" multiple />
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

UPDATE: I googled all the examples for this uploader and they all have only image upload field and nothing else. I need a solution when I have actually more fields in the form. Class dropzone can't be on whole form because I have more fields in it This is not just an image uploader!

I tried with this:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

  $("#pics").dropzone({
    url: '/ads/new',
    maxFilesize: 1
  });
```

And there are no errors but whole dropzone functionality is gone.

Btw. If you don't know how to help then there is no need to downvote.

Comment: From the docs `Don’t forget to specify an url option if you’re not using a form element, since Dropzone doesn’t know where to post to without an action attribute.` may be it would be good if you'd share your js or complete form

Comment: I actually don't have js for Dropzone, it is very confusing to me how this library works with PHP. Update: I have added some javascript code found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997927/dropzone-uncaught-error-no-url-provided but I get classic jquery error Dropzone not defined...

Comment: Is the input type file enclosed within a `<form>` ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Image upload is just a part of the form

Comment: please update your question with the code including the form that you are using

Comment: I have used dropzone in Laravel 5.4 in combination with JQuery. I'm not able to provide the answer now right away but I could give it to you later today if you want.

Comment: That would be very kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this might be help you

```
<form action="/ads/new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone">
<input class="input" type="text" name="name">
<input name="file" type="file"  multiple />
```

Comment: If I use dropzone class on a whole form then rest of the stuff is basically unusable and ugly. CSS get completely screwed.

Comment: can you provide snapshot of screwed css?

Comment: Unfortunately no, too much work just to show something I know is broken.

Comment: I can show you this http://d.pr/i/S3XpJ/3evQyxhq
This is when I apply it to only image upload item

Answer (score 0):

To make dropzone work in Laravel you can use the example below. Change it to your desired behaviour of course.

---

**HTML**

```
<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone"></form>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var baseUrl = "{{ url('/') }}";
            var token = "{{ Session::token() }}";

            $("#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({
                paramName: 'file',
                url: baseUrl+"/ads/new",
                params: {
                    _token: token
                },
                dictDefaultMessage: "Drop or click to upload images",
                clickable: true,
                maxFilesize: 2,
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                removedfile: function(file) {
                    // @TODO : Make your own implementation to delete a file
                },
                queuecomplete: function() {
                    // @TODO : Ajax call to load your uploaded files right away if required
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

**Laravel Upload Function for route: /ads/new**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File; // Required Dependencies
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

public function upload() {
        $destinationPath = public_path() . '/uploads/'; // upload folder, set whatever you like
        $fileNameWithExtension = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();

        $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $fileNameWithExtension); // uploading file to given path

        if ($upload_success) {
            return Response::json('success', 200);
        } else {
            return Response::json('error', 400);
        }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned before, my form has other stuff in it. Declaring dropzone class on a form element completely destroys my form. I tried your code to see what happens = nothing.

Comment: @KiraArik Your problem may be elsewhere because this code works for css and js file uploads too

Comment: But this is again just for one input within the form. Images. Nothing else. And I have several other items in my form that I have to process.